# How to access shared mailbox's Contacts Address Book in Outlook programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I have four mailboxes in my Outlook 2013 client at work, my personal (Me@MyCompany.Com) and the other three are shared mailboxes for projects/teams I am on, for example, (Sales@MyCompany.Com), (ProjectFinance@MyCompany.Com), etc.

I am using C# and can access the Contacts Address Book for my own mailbox just fine, but I would like to know how to access another mailbox's Contacts?

This works fine when accessing my own Contacts:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder myContactsFolder = application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

What is the equivalent for say mailbox (Sales@MyCompany.Com)?  I do have the username and password for this account just in case you need it but I don't believe you need it since I am creating an AddIn that will be used during the user's active session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call Namespace.CreateRecipient and pass the returned Recipient object to the Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a store specific default folder using the [GetDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Store class. So, you can iterate over all stores in the profile and get store-specific folders. The Namespace class provides the [Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864790(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Stores collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile.

See [How to: Enumerate Folders on All Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868170(v=office.15).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I don't see how a Store pertains to the Contacts Address Book (CAB)? Why would the Store solution deviate from the solution I used above for my profile's CAB? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use the `store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)`; method?